# Minecraft Computercraft Rednet.broadcast() isn't passing the proper value

Tags: lua, computercraft

The full code itself is very convoluted, long, and novice-written; I'm trying to send x and z coordinates via rednet from a computer to a separate receiver turtle.

*Receiver*

```
rednet.broadcast("Awaiting Input!")
xAxis = rednet.receive() --Have tried tonumber(rednet.receive()) on both same result
zAxis = rednet.receive()
rednet.broadcast(xAxis) --Both values return 2 regardless of what I enter in the sender.
rednet.broadcast(zAxis)
```

*sender*

```
if(irrelevant == "genericstringhere") then
    print(rednet.recieve()) --Awaiting Input!
    io.write("X Axis: ") --Pizzaz
    message = io.read() --Have tried using terms like X and xAxis.
    rednet.broadcast(message) --Broadcast whatever tf I typed in.
    sleep(0.3)
    io.write("Z Axis: ") --More Pizzaz
    message = io.read() --Have tried using terms like Z or zAxis
    rednet.broadcast(message) --Broadcast whatever tf I typed in. again.
    print(rednet.receive()) --Receive xAxis value from sender.
    print(rednet.receive()) --Receive zAxis value from sender.
end
```

Both results at the end of execution return 2 instead of the value I input in `io.read()`. I have tried `tonumber()`, `tostring()`, and every combination of the two, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation for `rednet.receive`](https://computercraft.info/wiki/Rednet.receive):

> **Returns**   *number* senderID, *any* message, *string* protocol

The 2 you're seeing is the sender ID, not the message. Instead of `xAxis = rednet.receive()`, do `senderId, xAxis = rednet.receive()`, and similarly for everywhere else you assign its value. (If you were wondering why `print` showed you numbers before the messages, that's why.)